# elRTE & elFinder callback issues

Tags: jquery, elfinder, elrte

I've successfully integrated elRTE with elFinder.

When I click the insert image icon from the toolbar, the image successfully gets added to my editor.
My issue is that when I click the open file icon, elFinder opens as you would expect but I cannot select a file to return back to elRTE.

Could someone assist me in getting a text / html file to open up in elRTE from elFinder?

**Working Example:** http://jsbin.com/esejuw/1/edit

Many Thanks

Comment: dude did you fix this?,

Comment: @MonchoChavez No, sorry.

Comment: I fix it updating to latest version also take a look here http://jsbin.com/otedag

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps, i have the same problem i just update to latest version files in the site, and follow this guide, https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Integration-with-elRTE-1.x

They even post a source where you can copy the code, you´ll see that way works perfectly like charm.

Demo 1 (source) http://jsbin.com/otedag/edit

Also pls note at the bottom where you can read:

UPDATE (delagen): if don't work try this update:

```
    instead of

    getFileCallback: callback
    write this:
    getFileCallback: function(file) { callback(file.path); }
```

UPDATE I have found the above two suggestions cause errors and this line works:

```
    getFileCallback: function(file) { callback(file.url); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Even this way moved.

```js
    $(function() {
      $('.wysiwyg').elrte({
        height   : 450,
        fmOpen : function(callback) {
          $('<div/>').dialogelfinder({
            url : './connector.php',
            commandsOptions: {
              getfile : {
                oncomplete : 'destroy',
                onlyURL : true  // <- Look at
              }
            },
            getFileCallback :callback
          });
        }
      });
    });
```